# Rails 5 Nested form, parent doesn't saved

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms, ruby-on-rails-5

I have hard time with this one.  I have an album Model and a Track Model, Track belongs to album  and album has many tracks. When I try to create an album with a track(the nested form below) it fails to save and renser the 'new' form with this message:

> 1 error prohibited this album from being saved: Tracks album must
>   exist

*Albums Controller*

```
class Admin::AlbumsController < AdminController    
  def new
    @album = Album.new
    @album.tracks.build
  end

  def create
    @album = Album.new(album_params)

    if @album.save
        redirect_to admin_album_path(@album)
    else
        render 'new'
    end
  end

  private

    def album_params
        params.require(:album).permit(:title, :kind, :release, tracks_attributes: [:id, :title, :time, :order])
    end
end
```

*Album Model*

```
class Album < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :tracks
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :tracks
end
```

*Track Model*

```
class Track < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :album
end
```

*Form*

```
<%= form_for [:admin, @album] do |f| %>

    <% if @album.errors.any? %>
        <div id="error_explanation">
            <h2>
                <%= pluralize(@album.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this album from being saved:
            </h2>
            <ul>
                <% @album.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
                <li><%= msg %></li>
                <% end %>
            </ul>
        </div>
    <% end %>

    <h5>Album</h5>
    <p>
        <%= f.label :title %><br>
        <%= f.text_field :title %>
    </p>

    <p>
        <%= f.label :kind %><br>
        <%= f.text_field :kind %>
    </p>

    <p>
        <%= f.label :release %><br>
        <%= f.text_field :release %>
    </p>
    <br><br><br>

    <h5>Track</h5>
    <%= f.fields_for :tracks do |tracks_form| %>
        <p>
            <%= tracks_form.label :title %>
            <%= tracks_form.text_field :title %>
        </p>
        <p>
            <%= tracks_form.label :time %>
            <%= tracks_form.text_field :time %>
        </p>
        <p>
            <%= tracks_form.label :order %>
            <%= tracks_form.text_field :order %>
        </p>
    <% end %>

    <%= f.submit class: "waves-effect waves-light btn" %>

<% end %>
```

I  think album doesn’t saved so track can’t get the album id.
Could you help me to figure out what really happens?

Comment: You can't build a relationship off an object that hasn't been persisted.  You'll notice that an object isn't assigned an ID in the database until then!  Therefore, instead you must create the album and then you can associate tracks to it via the album.tracks.new(params here)

Comment: Did you try same thins in console? Can you show migration for this models?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When Rails attempts to save the track, the album has not yet been committed into the database. In order for this to to work you need to have the 
*:inverse_of*

Try this

```
class Album < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :tracks, inverse_of: :album
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :tracks
end

class Track < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :album, inverse_of: :tracks
    validates_presence_of :album
end
```